# Join on less fields if no match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Let's say I have the following query:

```
select p.PetID, o.*
from Pet p
left join Owner o
on p.OwnerName = o.OwnerName
and p.Country = o.Country
and p.Address = o.Address
and p.Ref = o.Ref
```

If there's no matches for a Pet I want to simplify join:

```
select p.PetID, o.*
from Pet p
left join Owner o
on p.OwnerName = o.OwnerName
and p.Country = o.Country
and p.Address = o.Address
```

if still 0 matches I need to simplify again:

```
select p.PetID, o.*
    from Pet p
    left join Owner o
    on p.OwnerName = o.OwnerName
    and p.Country = o.Country
```

and finally:

```
   select p.PetID, o.*
   from Pet p
   left join Owner o
   on p.OwnerName = o.OwnerName
```

My current solution:

insert into temp table and then select from temp table where ownerId is null and have 4 separate queries. But my datasets are very large and this is not very efficient.

Pet table - 25 columns, 1.5mil records 
Owner table - 10 columns, 3mil records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple `left join`s:

```
select p.PetID, . . .
from Pet p left join
     Owner o1
     on p.OwnerName = o1.OwnerName and
        p.Country = o1.Country and
        p.Address = o1.Address and
        p.Ref = o1.Ref left join
     Owner o2
     on p.OwnerName = o2.OwnerName and
        p.Country = o2.Country and
        p.Address = o2.Address and
        o1.Ref is null left join
     Owner o3
     on p.OwnerName = o3.OwnerName and
        p.Country = o3.Country and
        o2.Ref is null left join
     Owner o4
     on p.OwnerName = o4.OwnerName and
        o3.Ref is null ;
```

You do need to fill in the `. . .` with something to get the columns from each of the tables.

Comment: But how do I avoid multiple columns from Owner table? Should I do coalesce(o1.OwnerID, o2.OwnerID, o3.OwnerID) as OwnerID?

Comment: @user194076 . . . Exactly.